# Logging errors in ASP.NET (MVC) through the Custom Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my web.config I have the following:

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="/error.aspx"/>
```

When an error occurs, the user is redirected to /error.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/somepage where I can get user's name, name of the page, date, but... I can't get the error message!

I can get it via the OnException method, but then I won't be able to get the name of the page which is very important for me.

How can I get both the page and the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by using Application_Error method.

More info here:

http://aspnetresources.com/articles/CustomErrorPages.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use
"ELMAH (Error Logging Modules and Handlers) is an application-wide error logging facility that is completely pluggable. It can be dynamically added to a running ASP.NET web application, or even all ASP.NET web applications on a machine, without any need for re-compilation or re-deployment"

http://code.google.com/p/elmah/